# How to translate parameters when replacing parameters in translation strings in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

The Laravel documentation says how to [add parameters to the translation string](https://docs.rularavel.com/docs/8.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings). But if you need to translate the parameter itself, how to do it?

There is an array of attributes in my translation file. But how do I use it?

Now I'm doing it like this:

```
__('validation.unique', [
    'attribute' => __('validation.attributes.' . $param)
]);
```

But I don't like this solution. Perhaps there is a better solution?

Comment: maybe explain what you are trying to solve here. Attribute are for the devs why translating them ?

Comment: @ml59 Why for developers?Attributes can be translated during validation in the FormRequest - so I'm interested in whether it is possible to automatically translate in other places?

Comment: FormRequest is not the best place for complex validation, I moved it to the service layer, but I want to return the error in the same format

Comment: I thought you wanted to translete the attribute itself like `:name`. If you are not using the Laravel Validation methods they won't be translated automatically

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @ml59 It seems that your comment is the correct answer